# How correctly build microservices arhitecture

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices

I'm new to microservice architecture.
I want to build microservices based on aws lambda.

Example:
I have two tables with posts and comments on them

How to properly build a microservices

I see it in this way:

Create the first service with crud(create, update, delete, show) posts and comments from the database

The second service will filter of posts and comments by specific parameters

If this arhitecture of services correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microservices are reusable services. In general, they do a "thing", and do it well. For example, a microservice can be generating a unique partition key for a table so there is no collision upon insert.

Your approach to microservices is fine. The objective is to decouple these microservices so that can be deployed independent of each other, and REUSE them as much as possible. Microservices begin to fail when people duplicate the core microservice (such as CRUD DB accessors) because they did not do their due diligence to discover what may already be available.

In good domain driven design, understanding ownership and responsibility of microservices is blatantly clear; so before jumping into microservices, I would look at doing a domain driven design activity.